# Javascript Help - If a certain text is found, change text color

Tags: javascript, text, colors

I'm looking for some help changing the code below to do not apply the second color if the text is not found. I intent to use the code more the once with other text according to the colors I and to change:

```
$(document).on('knack-view-render.any', function(event, view, data)     
{
    $("td.field_1416 > span , td.field_1416 > span > i").each(function() 
    {
        var cordaequipeROSA = ($(this).find("span").text().trim() == "Equipe Rosa") ? "#ff00ee" : "#a4b7c9";
        $(this).css("color", cordaequipeROSA);
    })
});
```

I want to remove the second color option an duplicate the code with other atributes, like this:

```
$(document).on('knack-view-render.any', function(event, view, data)     
{
    $("td.field_1416 > span , td.field_1416 > span > i").each(function() 
    {
        var cordaequipeBRANCA = ($(this).find("span").text().trim() == "Equipe BRANCA") ? "#fff" : "#a4b7c9";
        $(this).css("color", cordaequipeBRANCA);
    });
});
```

Does anyone know what should I change in the code to apply only one color per ($(this).find("span").text().trim() == "SEARCH_CRITERIA") ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="textbox">
<script>
    function changecolor() 
    {
        if textbox.value === "TEXT THAT SHOULD CHANGE COLOR") 
        {
            document.getElementById("textbox").style.color = 'THE COLOR THAT IT CHANGES TO';
        } 
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("textbox").style.color = 'black';
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => changecolor(), false)
</script>
```